# html5/css/js to make complex module-based software platforms (escaping from Adobe Flash)

Tags: javascript, css, html, flash

Recenly I was starting working at a software platform project using my own java-made Application Server and Adobe Flash as client side technology like I always did in the past, but this new work is a very long-term project and Flash today does not fit more: even though I consider Flash the most powerful clientside framework available worldwide, the destiny of Flash is not trustworthy for different reasons - we know. So I decided to add websockets support to my Application Server and to move clientside to html5/css/js (I had been on Flash since 2001.. I'm the last small business app producer gone away from Adobe I think).

the point: I'm at the early beginning of the move, and in my working model and by project default guideline I need to be able to load in realtime (a lot of) external software components from the web (which gives power to the development): all my past Flash/AIR-based apps were simply based on an initial first swf launcher which loads other application components (external swf) at bootstrap or when needed by the application itself.

is it possible to follow in some way the same implementation path with Javascript? need to work with modules.

thank you.

edit: **[‪#‎wantToBuildAnAwesomeRealTimeWebOSguiUsingJavascript‬]**

ps you can have a look to an implementation example of what I want to achieve (of course build with Flash) on the top of the homepage on my website: http://www.mc2labs.net, which is the app I was working at.

Answer (score 0):

There are several javascript frameworks that fit the description, here is a list of some of the first that comes to mind:

- AngularJS: http://www.angularjs.org
- ReactJS: http://facebook.github.io/react/
- Ember: http://emberjs.com/
- ...

The list could go on and on. Each framework as its own advantages/disadvantages and there is a lot of personal taste involved in the choice (my personnal favorite atm is angular, but react is quite impressive).

The [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) page can help you choose your javascript framework. It offers the same Todo app implemented in most major frameworks to see what fits your taste.

Most MV* frameworks work with some kind of modular approach.